# Can I use the jsonlite:toJSON method to convert a data frame or tibble into this specific format of deeply nested JSON?

Tags: r, json, dataframe

I'm working with the [Orbitly API](https://www.orbitly.io/api-documentation), and their API requires a JSON string in this specific format:

```
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "params": {
                "email": ["steve@woz.org"]
            }
        },
        {
            "params": {
                "profile": ["https://www.linkedin.com/in/brianchesky/"]
            }
        },
        {
            "params": {
                "phone": ["17186893174"]
            }
        },
        {
            "params": {
                "name": ["marc benioff"],
                "company": ["salesforce"]
            }
        }
    ],
    "required": "profiles.network:linkedin AND (phone_numbers OR emails)"
}
```

My data is currently in this format (imported from a spreadsheet):

```
> df
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  email         profile                                  phone       name         company   
  <chr>         <chr>                                    <chr>       <chr>        <chr>     
1 steve@woz.org NA                                       NA          NA           NA        
2 NA            https://www.linkedin.com/in/brianchesky/ NA          NA           NA        
3 NA            NA                                       17186893174 NA           NA        
4 NA            NA                                       NA          marc benioff salesforce
```

If I call the `jsonlite::toJSON` method, I can convert the data frame/tibble into a format that is sort of close, but understandably, it doesn't bundle anything into lists, and as far as I can tell, there's no way to force `toJSON` to use the somewhat unnatural bundling with `params` in front of everything:

```
> print(toJSON(df, simplifyVector=FALSE, pretty=TRUE))
[
  {
    "email": "steve@woz.org"
  },
  {
    "profile": "https://www.linkedin.com/in/brianchesky/"
  },
  {
    "phone": "17186893174"
  },
  {
    "name": "marc benioff",
    "company": "salesforce"
  }
]
```

Is my only hope to get this data frame into the right format some manually string appending? Or is there a more clever way to apply the `toJSON` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
jsonlite::toJSON(list(
    requests=unname(do.call(Map, c(list(f=function(...) list(params = Filter(Negate(is.na), list(...)))), df))), 
    required="profiles.network:linkedin AND (phone_numbers OR emails)"), 
  pretty = TRUE)
# {
#   "requests": [
#     {
#       "params": {
#         "email": ["steve@woz.org"]
#       }
#     },
#     {
#       "params": {
#         "profile": ["https://www.linkedin.com/in/brianchesky/"]
#       }
#     },
#     {
#       "params": {
#         "phone": ["17186893174"]
#       }
#     },
#     {
#       "params": {
#         "name": ["marc benioff"],
#         "company": ["salesforce"]
#       }
#     }
#   ],
#   "required": ["profiles.network:linkedin AND (phone_numbers OR emails)"]
# }
```

---

Data

```r
df <- structure(list(email = c("steve@woz.org", NA, NA, NA), profile = c(NA, "https://www.linkedin.com/in/brianchesky/", NA, NA), phone = c(NA, NA, "17186893174", NA), name = c(NA, NA, NA, "marc benioff"), company = c(NA, NA, NA, "salesforce")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 4L))
```

Comment: Doesn't this break up rows if multiple variables have data in them? In the API's required format, `marc benioff` and `salesforce` are together in the JSON.

Comment: I realized after the fact that my example was broken and didn't show that. My apologies on that. Your answer is still extremely close to what I'm looking for, I think. Sorry I should have made sure the question was accurate, so sorry to edit it after the fact.

Comment: Your last edit did nothing to demonstrate this effect or what you expect to happen with it. I was not using the `df` in your question, so changing that didn't change how this performs.

Comment: I don't know if I can fit the entire string here, but using your `df` and your code produces a string includes this: `{"params": {"name": ["marc benioff"]}},{"params": {"company": ["salesforce"]}}`
whereas it should produce something like in my question, with this: `{"params": {"name": ["marc benioff"],"company": ["salesforce"]}}`. Data points that are in the same row in the data (as they are in your `df` too) should be in the _same_ `params` in the final result, as in the API documentation.

Comment: See my edit, I think that's what you originally requested, sorry about missing that.

Comment: Thank you. I stored the result as `df_as_json` and then called `df_as_json$required <- unbox(df_as_json$required)` because this API requires everything to be in a list _except_ the `required` parameter. Your code was just what I needed though! Thank you!